# Collections are deleted by themselves in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a problem with MongoDB when I try to create a collection. That is, I create it and then i check it with the commands:

```
db.mycollection.find()
```

or

```
db.mycollection.count()
```

And the data comes out, however, after a certain time (minutes), the data of the collections are eliminated by themselves, that is to say they are not persisted, what is happening?
Thanks.

Comment: [ttl](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) collection ? To be sure `db.mycollection.getIndexes()`

Comment: Hi, i get this: [  ]

Comment: Can you show the full process please. With the create and the logs and then the find/count ?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I just saw and when manually inserted in the shell, the collections if they are saved. However when I add them from Play Framework 2.6 and reactivemongo are not saved but persist in the browser, I do not know what happens.

Comment: I just fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @MiguelUrbinaRodríguez What was the issue and how did you fix it?